# Gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 4 (Ubuntu) heat map issue

Tags: plot, gnuplot, heatmap

I have two problems with generating a heat map via XYZ data from a txt file.
First the plot is really strange, something like this:

[image: Strange heatmap plot]

Here is my script which is providing this plot:

```
set term png size 1024,600
set output 'parameterter.2.png'
unset key
set view map

set tics scale 0

set nocbtics

set title "Paramétertér" 
set xlabel"s"
set ylabel"mutrata"

set xtics 0.15
set ytics (2e-5, 2e-4, 2e-3, 0.02 , 0.2) 

set xrange [ 0.00000 : 0.6000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set yrange [ 0.00002 : 0.2000 ] noreverse nowriteback

set cblabel "Rákosodás mértéke (db szimuláció)" 
set cbrange [ 0.00000 : 50.00000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set palette rgbformulae 33, 13, 10

plot "param.txt" matrix using 1:2:3 with image
```

Secondly I've searched for this but I couldn't find anything like how can I make the ytics distance constant, like I have in my script a 10 multiplier between ytics like `0.00002`,  `-0.0002`, `-0.002` etc. and I want to make equally wide "boxes" from them in the heat map...

The plot what you can see generated by these two data files (Tester and Original):
http://pastebin.com/5cbVVvcr

Sorry if it's too trivial or something I was searching a lot and I couldn't find a suitable answere...

Thank you very much!

Comment: are you sure your data doesn't need a `set log y` ?

Comment: thx I've figured it out!:D

Comment: Glad to know. Now it would be nice to share your answer to the problem. Stackoverflow will give you reputation for this! http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer